# Should compressed and uncompressed sizes be equal for a stored file in Central File Header?

Tags: zip

If a file is not compressed (i.e. stored) in a ZIP file, would its corresponding Central File Header entry have the same compressed and uncompressed sizes? Or is it possible that one of these will be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should have both sizes, where compressed size is greater or equal to not-compressed.
It can be greater when encryption is used.